# JRE failed even after open jdk as well as oracle ... using ubuntu14.04

Tags: java

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority       Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java  1069          auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java  1069         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1            manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

---

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

But when I try to install my bin tool:

```
$ ./DS41Client.bin 

      Initializing InstallShield Wizard........
      Extracting Bundled JRE.          

                Bundled JRE is not binary compatible with host OS/Arch 
                or it is corrupt.  Testing bundled JRE failed.
```

Can you please tell what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

As the last error message stated, your binary includes its own JRE, which is likely a 32 bits JRE.

You should use the 64 bits version of `./DS41Client.bin`.

Note: Actually, installing multi-lib packages of your distro **could** help, but since your binary seems to do its own checking, I think it won't work (maybe it only check the kernel version or something like that...)